# Best way to extend a container in full screen

Tags: html, css

I have researched a bit and saw many examples about how developers use this technique to full screen a container and the most used are:

```
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

and

```
html, body{
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
}

.container {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

These are the most used methods to extend a div in full screen when the container is the child of body.

If you ask me, the method using absolute position is not a very good idea because if you put other elements inside you can not relate to it because they have an absolute position.

The method using HTML and body 100% seems to be a little bit rudimentary.

**So, what is the best way to extend a container?**

Comment: Full screen, it´s better use view port measure - https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/

Comment: _"if you put other elements inside you can not relate to it because have a absolute position"_. I'm sorry, but this doesn't make sense. What is the **exact** problem you're facing? What have you tried to solve it?

Comment: @ Luis P. A this sesm to be a great solution, to be fair I never heard about these units .